# Solution on modifying summary view on custom module using Vtiger CRM 7

Tags: php

This is my preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iy6o.png)

Are there any solution about to modify summary view in custom module using Vtiger CRM 7; I have created 2 files, but didn't get it same view is there please give proper solution for this Vtiger CRM 7 in a proper way?

Comment: vivek85 give solution